# Can Shiny Use Mirai to Take Advantage of Multiple Cores

Tags: r, shiny

Suppose there is a busy site that executes a 5s calculation when a user clicks a button. We know that R is single threaded, so if it's busy working on user_1's calculation, user_2 must wait.

{[mirai](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/04/re-introducing-mirai-a-minimalist-async-evaluation-framework-for-r/)} is a minimalist async evaluation framework for R.

I'm wondering whether `mirai` will automatically distribute each individual users calculation over the number of cores that a machine has so as to minimize wait time.

The calculations of each of user are independent from one another.

```
library(shiny)
library(mirai)

daemons(2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
   
    call_mirai(
      takes_a_few_sec(a, b, c)
    ) 
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: shiny's official async programming pattern is based on [library(future) / library(promises)](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/intro.html).